# data replication and master

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have a web based system in php that works locally in multiple places and in each place has a local database in mysqli.

Also my system in every place connect remotely to another database that get all of information from specific tables of local systems as an example when you insert a record in any place,this record insert to remote database ,too. and so on ,to tell summary sync information from local to remote database.

[schema of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jn8.jpg)

Now I know replication can be  a good idea for this.

but I don't know when my remote database has a problem and my system can't connected to remote database how to apply changes in local database to remote database?

Comment: To solve this you can apply multiple distributed DB implementation plans. Its better to follow some tutorials first and then try the most suitable pattern by yourself. Post here for an exact answer with info about what you have already done.

Comment: @kuma-dk using of replication is a bad idea in this case?

Comment: If your local application cannot connect to the remote database / synchronisation layer, then there is no way to apply any changes.

Comment: Maybe for a short time my master can't be accessable

Comment: Search for "occasionally connected applications data synchronization"